# Solr 4.7.2 , Able to Import a Big XML, Issue while Importing using FileListEntityProcessor

Tags: xml, solr, dataimporthandler

I am able to Import a big XML file using data import handler, Then tried importing multiple files using FileListEntityProcessor, by following instruction given at solr wiki.
The Issue is, It is parsing complete file( the time taken is same as single file import; and there is only one *.xml file in directory), not showing any error, and showing success message. But not creating Index ( If I do a search, shows no result).
I had a guess that some issue with xpath etc, so I did check. 
Any clue / solution 'll help me.

Thanks in advance!

The Data-Config xml

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="FileDataSource" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <document>
<entity
        name="pickupdir"
        processor="FileListEntityProcessor"
        rootEntity="false"
        dataSource="null"
        fileName="^.*\.xml$"
        baseDir="/media/200GB"
        recursive="false"
    >
<entity 
        name="page"
        processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
      transformer="DateFormatTransformer,TemplateTransformer,RegexTransformer,LogTransformer"
        url="${pickupdir.fileAbsolutePath}"
        forEach="/rootnode/page/" >
    <field column="id"        xpath="/rootnode/page/id" />
        <field column="title"     xpath="/rootnode/page/title" />
        <field column="revision"  xpath="/rootnode/page/revision/id" />
        <field column="user"      xpath="/rootnode/page/revision/contributor/username" />
        <field column="userId"    xpath="/rootnode/page/revision/contributor/id" />
        <field column="text"      xpath="/rootnode/page/revision/text" />
        <field column="timestamp" xpath="/rootnode/page/revision/timestamp" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'" />
        <field column="$skipDoc"  regex="^#REDIRECT .*" replaceWith="true" sourceColName="text"/>
</entity>
</entity>
    </document>
    </dataConfig>
```

Comment: Please provide some example code that helps to explain your question.

Comment: Sure, just posted The Data Config xml.

Comment: The machine used was of 4GB RAM Duel core processor, and file size 50+ GB.

Comment: Same configuration is working on 16GB RAM system. Thanks